# reqwest::client does not have get method

Tags: rust, gzip, reqwest

According to [this example](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.8.4/reqwest/struct.ClientBuilder.html#example-3), I should be able to run `get` on a client instantiated with client builder:

```
use reqwest::header;
let mut headers = header::Headers::new();
headers.set(header::Authorization("secret".to_string()));

// get a client builder
let client = reqwest::Client::builder()
    .default_headers(headers)
    .build()?;
let res = client.get("https://www.rust-lang.org").send()?;
```

Below is the code that I have written.

```
let client = Client::builder()
        .gzip(true)
        .timeout(Duration::from_secs(10))
        .build();
let resp = client.get("https://wiki.mozilla.org/images/f/ff/Example.json.gz");
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `get` found for type `std::result::Result<reqwest::Client, reqwest::Error>` in the current scope
  --> examples/gzipped_http_files.rs:86:23
   |
86 |     let resp = client.get("https://wiki.mozilla.org/images/f/ff/Example.json.gz");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to test the result coming out of `.build()`. Notice the `?` operator in the original example.

Comment: Or use `.build().expect("Could not build the client")`, etc.

Comment: This got me through. Thanks @E_net4